# Moisture Sensor Resistance

Tags: resistance, multimeter, ohmmeter

I have made a soil moisture sensor by taking two lines of Veroboard and soldering a wire to each line. The theory is that the resistance will change with the moisture - resistance dropping as the moisture rises.

However, with my new LCR meter, I am getting a difference of a whole megaohm depending on which range I use to measure it.

What result should I trust?

> Notes:
>   Using a regular multimeter is not an option. My regular multimeter is very old and imprecise and I am a poor student who wants to finish this project before his significant other's birthday.

Comment: Perhaps there's a problem with your "theory"... What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: For water you need to do an AC measurement.

Comment: I am trying to turn on an LED when the water gets dry.

Comment: I would appreciate some extra information with that AC comment.

Comment: @DaveTweed, What's wrong with his theory? Soil resistance does indeed change with moisture level. Google it yourself. You can find a hundreds of toy "plant watering" electronics projects to do just this. Capacitance between two electrodes also changes with moisture level. This is a better way to measure since you can completely seal the electrodes, protecting them from corrosion.